# Equivalent of Hist()'s Layout hyperparameter in Sns.Pairplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, scatter-plot, pairplot

Am trying to find `hist()`'s `figsize` and `layout` parameter for `sns.pairplot()`.

I have a `pairplot` that gives me nice scatterplots between the X's and y. However, it is oriented horizontally and there is no equivalent `layout` parameter to make them vertical to my knowledge. 4 plots per row would be great.

This is my current `sns.pairplot():`

```
sns.pairplot(X_train,
  x_vars = X_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns,
  y_vars = ["SalePrice"])
```

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like: [Source](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hernnvignolo/house-prices-art-without-data-leakage#5.-Machine-Learning-model-for-predictions)

```
num_mask = train_df.dtypes != object
num_cols = train_df.loc[:, num_mask[num_mask == True].keys()]
num_cols.hist(figsize = (30,15), layout = (4,10))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is `hist()`?

Comment: @mwaskom: Probably pandas' [`DataFrame.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) is meant here. Avoiding the need for `melt` in seaborn's `FacetGrid` functions seems quite complex given the many options available, and would create more confusion than it would solve.

Comment: yep Dataframe's hist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve isn't currently supported by `sns.pairplot`, but you can use one of the other [figure-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) (`sns.displot`, `sns.catplot`, ...).  `sns.lmplot` creates a grid of scatter plots. For this to work, the dataframe needs to be in ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Here is a simple example. [`sns.lmplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) has parameters to leave out the regression line (`fit_reg=False`), to set the height of the individual subplots (`height=...`), to set its aspect ratio (`aspect=...`, where the subplot width will be height times aspect ratio), and many more. If all y ranges are similar, you can use the default `sharey=True`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some test data with different y-ranges
np.random.seed(20230209)
X_train = pd.DataFrame({"".join(np.random.choice([*'uvwxyz'], np.random.randint(3, 8))):
                            np.random.randn(100).cumsum() + np.random.randint(100, 1000) for _ in range(10)})
X_train['SalePrice'] = np.random.randint(10000, 100000, 100)

# convert the dataframe to long form
# 'SalePrice' will get excluded automatically via `melt`
compare_columns = X_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns
long_df = X_train.melt(id_vars='SalePrice', value_vars=compare_columns)

# create a grid of scatter plots
g = sns.lmplot(data=long_df, x='SalePrice', y='value', col='variable', col_wrap=4, sharey=False)
g.set(ylabel='')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lmplot for a grid of scatter plots]

Here is another example, with histograms of the mpg dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

compare_columns = mpg.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns
mpg_long = mpg.melt(value_vars=compare_columns)
g = sns.displot(data=mpg_long, kde=True, x='value', common_bins=False, col='variable', col_wrap=4, color='crimson',
                facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False})
g.set(xlabel='')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot for a list of numeric columns]

Comment: Awesome it looks like it worked for me! One follow up, is there a way to make the font bigger? It is really small and `g.set(font_scale = 2)` does not work on my end.

Comment: You can set the scale before creating the plot by calling `sns.set(font_scale=2)`